# Grid reordering items on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have a basic grid layout:

```css
.container{
   display:grid;
   gap:20px;
   grid-template-columns: repeat (12, 1fr)
}
.container >*{
   grid-column-start: span 12
}
@media(min-width:768px){
   .item{
      grid-column-start:span 6
   }  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
    <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
    <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
    <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
</div>
```

How can I have the image in the second row on the right on screen sizes above 768px, and the text on the left?

Comment: I'm confused. On large screens you don't have the two side by side.

Comment: @ralph.m yes, the snippet above does not show them correctly, but the css  rule .item{
      grid-column-start:span 6   }  makes it two-columns on larger screens.

Comment: Ah, right. Duh. Sorry. Okay, I've posted an answer that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```css
.container{
  display:grid;
  gap:20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr)
}
.container >*{
  grid-column-start: span 12
}
@media(min-width:768px){
  .item { grid-column-start:span 6;} 
  .item:nth-child(4n-1) {grid-column: 7 / span 6;}
  .item:nth-child(4n) {grid-column: 1 / span 6;}
  .container {grid-auto-flow: dense;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
  <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
  <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
  <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
  <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
  <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
  <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that places every text on the left and every image on the right.

Comment: So you just want this on the second row only? It's easy to tweak if that's the case. EDIT: I've updated it to that effect, in case that's what you wanted.

Comment: thank you! I actually do want it for every even row, but using odd and even does not work for some reason. Whereas specific numbers for nth-child work...

Comment: Ah, I see. Just for fun, I updated the code again so that you don't have to hard code every row.

Answer (score 0):

To have the image in the second row on the right on screen sizes above 768px and the text on the left, you can update your code.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.container > * {
  grid-column-start: span 12;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item:nth-child(even) {
    grid-column-start: span 6;
    grid-row-start: 1;
  }

  .item:nth-child(odd) {
    grid-column-start: span 6;
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
  <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
  <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="..."></div>
  <div class="item"><p>Text</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this does not work unfortunately. The items are all squished into the wrong columns.

Comment: <style>
  .container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  }

  .item:nth-child(even) {
    grid-column: span 6;
    grid-row: 2;
  }

  .item:nth-child(odd) {
    grid-column: span 6;
    grid-row: 1;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .item {
      grid-column: span 12;
      grid-row: auto;
    }
  }
</style>

Comment: You can try this it will work accordingly

Comment: no, that places images on top , both in one row, and both texts in the next row.